Deserialize XML with unknown xsi:type attribute
I am trying to Deserialize XML and having trouble defining xsi:type which could be something new.
I need to read child nodes of AutxObject irrespective of type, child element nodes are fixed and always available.
XML
    <AutxObject xsi:type="TYPEA">
      <ID>6cbe7c6f-79e8-4006-b7e9-11e25e2a0f8e</ID>
      <Name>Queue</Name>
      <ProcessID>eaab59cd-2be4-46fe-86c4-ee96c340c061</ProcessID>
      <IsRemoteExecutionEnabled>false</IsRemoteExecutionEnabled>
      <IsolationPlatform>x86</IsolationPlatform>
      <IsolationSessionType>Current</IsolationSessionType>
      <Items />
      <RootPath>Global Objects</RootPath>
    </AutxObject>
    <AutxObject xsi:type="TYPEB">
      <ID>9c643856-5f0c-497a-b212-a2e456d1a821</ID>
      <Name>Sample</Name>
      <ProcessID>eaab59cd-2be4-46fe-86c4-ee96c340c061</ProcessID>
      <IsRemoteExecutionEnabled>false</IsRemoteExecutionEnabled>
      <IsolationPlatform>x86</IsolationPlatform>
      <IsolationSessionType>Current</IsolationSessionType>
      <Items />
      <RootPath>Global Objects</RootPath>
      <Type>
        <ID>75f2bd69-8bfc-41ba-a3fc-32e1a438b23a</ID>
        <Name>Object</Name>
        <FullName>System.Object</FullName>
        <Assembly>mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</Assembly>
      </Type>
    </AutxObject>

Class
 [XmlInclude(typeof(TYPEA))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(TYPEB))]
    public class GlobalVariable
    {
        [XmlElement("ID")]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [XmlElement("RootPath")]
        public string RootPath { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    [XmlType(TypeName = "TYPEA")]
    public class TYPEA: GlobalVariable { }

    [XmlType(TypeName = "TYPEB")]
    public class TYPEB: GlobalVariable { }

But what if there are new types? How to serialize unknow xsi types. The child nodes would still be same.

"which could be something new" - Do you appreciate how dangerous it is to allow any type to be deserialized automatically?

I can get this to work, but best way if you learn how to debug yourself. What I would recommend is to add data to the c# classes and then serialize the c#. Then compare your serialized xml against the xml file you are trying to deserialize.  Then modify the c# classes until you get the same results as your input xml.

You need to change from : public class GlobalVariable  to : public class AutxObject or add above line [XmlRoot("AutxObject")]

BTW, if your problem here is not that you want to allow any type to be instantiated, but that you want to deserialize <AutxObject> elements such that you preserve all XML attributes and elements, then use [XmlAnyAttribute] and [XmlAnyElement].

@Dai Yes, I am aware. XML will be generated by internal tools and I am just trying to parse it for some report generation.
And thanks for the suggestion- that is what I am looking for, I will look into [XmlAnyAttribute] and [XmlAnyElement]

What do you want to do in case an unknown xsi:type is encountered?  Fall back to the base type GlobalVariable?  Skip the element?  Or do something else?  And do you expect to be able to preserve the xsi:type value somewhere so it can be re-serialized?
